# Mongoose busqueda entre 2 collections

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

tengo una duda que me gustaria saber como resolver. Hace ya varios dias buscando info

Necesito obtener informacion de 2 collections relaciodados. (Users, Comments)
La collection **Users** tiene un campo de tipo array llamado 'comments' el cual almacena los **ids** de los comments que tiene ese usuario, ahora bien, la consulta que quiero realizar es Obtener todos los usuarios que tengan comentarios y filtrarlos por un valor de la collection 'comments'

Estructura de modelo de las collections:

```js
const users = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  lastname: String,
  age: Number,
  comments: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Comments',
    }
  ],
}, { timestamp: true, strict: false });

const comments = new mongoose.Schema({
  message: {
    type: String,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
  },
  candidates: Number,
  
}, { timestamp: true, strict: false });
```

Me gustaría obtener los **users** que contengan comentarios cuyo "candidates" sean mayor a 100

Intenté hacer esto, pero no funcionó:

```js
let users = await Users.aggregate([

    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'comments',
        let: { candidates: "$candidates" },
        pipeline: [
          { $match:
            { $expr:
               { $and:
                  [
                    
                    { $gte: [ "$candidates", 100 ] }
                  ]
               }
            }
         },
         
        ],
        as: 'asValues'

      },
    },
    { $sort: sort },
    { $skip: skip },

  ])
```

¿Cuál sería la mejor manera de hacer esto?

Comment: ¿De dónde sale eso del _pipeline_ y _let_ dentro del stage de _$lookup_? Los atributos que necesitas según la documentación son _from_, _localField_, _foreignField_ y _as_. Como dice en la [documentación](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: Hola, fijate la documentación en el mismo link que me pasaste, abajo comenta lo del pipeline

Comment: Ohhh, ya lo veo. Mi error, no me había tocado usarlo así. En todo caso si te llega a complicar podrías primero hacer un _$lookup_ simple y luego el filtrado. Pero bueno, igual habría qué evaluar qué es más eficiente.

``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te debería funcionar algo como esto:

```
let users = await Users.aggregate([
    {
       $lookup: { //Obtienes los comentarios de cada usuario con candidates mayor o igual a 100
           from: "comments",
           let: { userComments: "$comments" }, //Guardas los ids de los comentarios en una variable para poder usarla en el pipeline
           pipeline: [
              {
                 $match: { 
                     $expr: { 
                         $and: [
                             { $gte: ["$candidates", 100] }, //Comparas que los candidates sean mayor a 100
                             { $in: ["$_id", "$$userComments"] } //Comparas que esos comentarios sean de este usuario
                         ]
                     }
                 }
              },
              { 
                 $count: "total" //Te interesa solo contarlos, no devolver la lista
              }
           ],
           as: "commentsWithCandidatesCount" //Nombre que le asignas a la propiedad
       }    
    },
    {
       $unwind: "$commentsWithCandidatesCount" //Le haces unwind para que un array se convierta en un valor unico (los que no tengan elementos se descartan de la lista de usuarios)
    },
    {
       $unset: "commentsWithCandidatesCount" //quitas esta propiedad que ya no la necesitas
    }
])
```

Comment: Tienes reputación suficiente para saber [answer]. Responder sólo con código se considera de baja calidad. Te invito a [edit] tu respuesta y agregar una pequeña explicación al código. Saludos

Comment: Considero que dejé suficientes comentarios dentro del código para explicarlo... no? Crees que es necesaria mas explicación?